# Xcode throws privacy error when I try accessing the webcam through OpenCv

Tags: xcode, opencv, webcam, privacy, info.plist

About a month ago I wrote a program in cpp on xcode that opened the camera with Opencv and was able to show the feed. Now, when I run it it throws

`[access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive 
data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an 
NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the 
user how the app uses this data.`

the only thing that I think could have changed was upgrading to Mac Mojave. It this the only source of the error since it worked before? Or can something else in my project be causing this to appear now?

Answer (score 1):

> If you link on or after iOS 10, or on or after macOS 10.14,
>   your app crashes if you try to access certain protected resources
>   without providing a corresponding purpose string. Even if it’s not
>   required, it’s always best to provide a usage string if your app uses
>   a protected resource.

[Accessing Protected Resources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/accessing_protected_resources)